Modal slideshow for multiple images on page
I was able to put together what I wanted but when multiple images are involved it combines them all in one slideshow.  The end goal is to have multiple images on the page.  When a particular image is clicked, it will open a slideshow of other images.  My current code works great, until a second image is added to the page because its referring to element id img01 for everything.  How can I make this JavaScript determine which image I am clicking on and only show the slideshow of images intended for it.
Just to make sure it's clear:

Click on Image 1 - Open slideshow with (Image 1, Image B, Image C)

Click on Image 2 - Open slideshow with (Image 2, Image E, Image F)


I tried separating each set of images into img1, img2, etc.. But I don't know how to do it without excessive code.
This is what I have so far:


var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01');
var currentImage;
for (var i = 0; i < img.length - 1; i++) {
  img[i].setAttribute('data', i);
  img[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.dataset.biggerSrc;
    currentImage = this;
    document.getElementById("modal-footer").innerHTML = "Image 1 of " + i;
  }
}

document.getElementById('prev').onclick = function() {
  var count = parseInt(currentImage.getAttribute("data"));
  if (count > 0) {
    currentImage = img[count - 1];
    document.getElementById("modal-footer").innerHTML = "Image " + count++ + " of " + i;
  }
  modalImg.src = currentImage.dataset.biggerSrc;
}

document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
  var count = parseInt(currentImage.getAttribute("data"));
  if (count < img.length - 2) {
    currentImage = img[count + 1];
    document.getElementById("modal-footer").innerHTML = "Image " + (count + 2) + " of " + i;;
  }
  modalImg.src = currentImage.dataset.biggerSrc;

}

document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0].onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}

.modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#modal-footer {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://placehold.co/300x150?text=slide 1" data-bigger-src="https://placehold.co/600x300?text=slide 1" width="300" height="150">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://placehold.co/300x150?text=slide 2" data-bigger-src="https://placehold.co/600x300?text=slide 2" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://placehold.co/300x150?text=slide 3" data-bigger-src="https://placehold.co/600x300?text=slide 3" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <a id="prev" class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a id="next" class="next">&#10095;</a>
    <div id="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://placehold.co/300x150?text=slide 1" data-bigger-src="https://placehold.co/600x300?text=slide 1" width="300" height="150">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://placehold.co/300x150?text=slide 2" data-bigger-src="https://placehold.co/600x300?text=slide 2" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">
  <img class="myImg" src="https://placehold.co/300x150?text=slide 3" data-bigger-src="https://placehold.co/600x300?text=slide 3" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">X</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <a id="prev" class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a id="next" class="next">&#10095;</a>
      <div id="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>




Ideally, you would use just a single modal. Also id should be unique across the elements.
So let's go with ideally and keep one modal. As for the images, we will first iterate by .container, taking images from each one. This code could use many improvements, but it works.


var modal = document.getElementById("myModal")
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container")
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01')
var modalFooter = document.getElementById("modal-footer")
var currentContainer = null
var currentImage = null

containers.forEach(function(container) {
  var imgs = container.querySelectorAll(".myImg")
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].setAttribute('data', i);
    imgs[i].onclick = function(ev) {
      currentContainer = container
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.dataset.biggerSrc;
      currentImage = this;
      modalFooter.innerHTML = "Image 1 of " + i + " of " + currentContainer.id;
    }
  }
})


document.getElementById('prev').onclick = function() {
  var count = parseInt(currentImage.getAttribute("data"));
  var imgs = currentContainer.querySelectorAll(".myImg")
  if (count > 0) {
    currentImage = imgs[count - 1]
    modalFooter.innerHTML = "Image " + count++ + " of " + imgs.length;
  }
  modalImg.src = currentImage.dataset.biggerSrc;
}

document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
  var count = parseInt(currentImage.getAttribute("data"));
  var imgs = currentContainer.querySelectorAll(".myImg")
  if (count < imgs.length - 1) {
    currentImage = imgs[count + 1]
    modalFooter.innerHTML = "Image " + (count + 2) + " of " + imgs.length;
  }
  modalImg.src = currentImage.dataset.biggerSrc;
}

document.querySelector(".close").onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
}

.modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#modal-footer {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 0;
}
<div id="gallery1" class="container">
  <img class="myImg" src="../images/17Csmall.PNG" data-bigger-src="../images/17C.PNG" width="300" height="150">
  <img class="myImg" src="../images/17C-a.PNG" data-bigger-src="../images/17C-a.PNG" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">
  <img class="myImg" src="../images/17C-b.PNG" data-bigger-src="../images/17C-b.PNG" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">
</div>

<div id="gallery2" class="container">
  <img class="myImg" src="../images/18Csmall.PNG" data-bigger-src="../images/18C.PNG" width="300" height="150">
  <img class="myImg" src="../images/18C-a.PNG" data-bigger-src="../images/18C-a.PNG" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">
  <img class="myImg" src="../images/18C-b.PNG" data-bigger-src="../images/18C-b.PNG" width="300" height="150" style="Display: none;">
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">X</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <a id="prev" class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a id="next" class="next">&#10095;</a>
  <div id="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>




This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!!!  I'm still new to JavaScript so I appreciate your help!
